# Footer. It overlaps on div

Tags: html, css

I've got a problem with the footer of my website. It overlaps to the content div. I've got a structure like this:

```css
#content {
  width: 80%;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: "Arial";
  clear: both;
}
#footer {
  font-family: "Arial";
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #E6E6E6;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: 70%;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="logo">
    <img logo here>
  </div>

  <div id="paragraph">
    <p>here
  </div>

  <div id="footer">
    Footer content
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that in one page I've got an image and a paragraph and it looks fine because it's not touching the footer position. But when I have text that need to be scrolled, the footer overlaps into it

Comment: Yes, that's what happens when you use absolute positioning.

Comment: Add a bottom margin equal to the height of your footer to your content div. Also, what Orlol said.

Comment: Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: Well, I'look into relative positioning then...thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its because you are using position:absolute; wich mean that any element with position absolute will be placed there no matter what, so you better use position:relative;

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div id="paragraph">
        <p> here is where you want to make your change.
    </div>
<style>
   #paragraph::after{
      margin-top:2px;
      margin-bottom:2px;
   }

   #footer{
   clear:both;
   }
</style>
```

Put the style in your .css file instead of inline like this. I just wrote it to get the point across.  The pseudo element "after" will add something "after" your id=paragraph element which should help with a bit of spacing between that and the footer.  In addition to that, adding "clear:both" to the footer element should insure whether you add the ":after" or not that your footer "clears" all elements above it in the HTML.  I added the 2px to provide a little cushioning. You can alter, or remove that as needed.  I would recommend leaving at a minimum a 1px line for either margin-top or margin-bottom so it's not an empty element though.

I agree in that you may want to remove "absolute" from your styling for the position as well.

Answer (score 0):

Change the footers position to `relative;`, currently the footer is sitting on top of the container div.

Because you're using `%` move the footer div out of it's container to lose any inherited properties.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp